# How to dim all miniframes at the end of a beamer presentation?

Tags: beamer, mini-frames

In beamer presentations I like to dim all of the miniframes for the first and last few slides of the talk (slides with introduction, conclusions, references, etc.; things that don't fit into any particular subsection of the talk). I used to be able to accomplish this by following each `\section` command with a `\stepcounter{subsection}` command, and also including a `\stepcounter{section}` command at the point in the talk where I'd like miniframes to be dimmed for all subsequent slides. This no longer works, and I am not sure why.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme[]{Madrid}
\useoutertheme[footline=empty,subsection=false]{miniframes}

\title{an awesome talk}
\author{a froody dude}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{slide 0}
All miniframes dimmed, as desired.
\end{frame}

\section{section 1}
\stepcounter{subsection}

\begin{frame}{slide 1}
content 1
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{slide 2}
content 2
\end{frame}

\section{section 2}
\stepcounter{subsection}

\begin{frame}{slide 3}
content 3
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{slide 4}
content 4
\end{frame}

\section{section 3}
\stepcounter{subsection}

\begin{frame}{slide 5}
shading on miniframes is wrong
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{slide 6}
shading on miniframes is wrong
\end{frame}

\stepcounter{section} % This command used to result in the desired effect.

\begin{frame}{slide 5}
all miniframes should be dimmed
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{slide 6}
all miniframes should be dimmed
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCNJg.jpg) is what I see when I compile the above document. It's hard to tell in the above image due to the compression, but the shading on slides 7

[image: seven]

and 8

[image: eight]

is messed up.

I am running Xubuntu 18.04, TexLive 2017.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The good new is that with the new beamer behaviour you don't need `\stepcounter{subsection}` anymore.

The bad news: switching off the miniframes needs a bit of a hack:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme[]{Madrid}
\useoutertheme[footline=empty,subsection=false]{miniframes}

\title{an awesome talk}
\author{a froody dude}
\date{\today}


\makeatletter
\let\beamer@writeslidentry@miniframeson=\beamer@writeslidentry%
\def\beamer@writeslidentry@miniframesoff{%
  \expandafter\beamer@ifempty\expandafter{\beamer@framestartpage}{}% does not happen normally
  {%else
    % removed \addtocontents commands
    \clearpage\beamer@notesactions%
  }
}
\newcommand*{\miniframeson}{\let\beamer@writeslidentry=\beamer@writeslidentry@miniframeson}
\newcommand*{\miniframesoff}{\let\beamer@writeslidentry=\beamer@writeslidentry@miniframesoff}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{slide 0}
All miniframes dimmed, as desired.
\end{frame}

\section{section 1}
%\stepcounter{subsection}

\begin{frame}{slide 1}
content 1
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{slide 2}
content 2
\end{frame}

\section{section 2}
%\stepcounter{subsection}

\begin{frame}{slide 3}
content 3
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{slide 4}
content 4
\end{frame}

\section{section 3}
%\stepcounter{subsection}

\begin{frame}{slide 5}
shading on miniframes is wrong
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{slide 6}
shading on miniframes is wrong
\end{frame}

\section{}
\miniframesoff

\begin{frame}{slide 5}
all miniframes should be dimmed
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{slide 6}
all miniframes should be dimmed
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @teerav42 You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Setting the counter to 0 seems to work. Note that you don't need to step the subsection counter manually.

Partial MWE:

```
\section{section 3}
%\stepcounter{subsection}

\begin{frame}{slide 5}
shading on miniframes is wrong
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{slide 6}
shading on miniframes is wrong
\end{frame}

\setcounter{section}{0}

\begin{frame}{slide 5}
all miniframes should be dimmed
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{slide 6}
all miniframes should be dimmed
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This worked in in the MWE I provided, but did not work when I tried to put it into the custom beamer theme I like using for my presentations. @samcarter 's solution worked for me though!